# Talend - Unable to send mail from tsendmail

Tags: talend

I have been trying to extract the data from DB and export the attachment through email.

But, I am getting the error below while trying:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3477
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tSendMail_1 (ABC)
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:322)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
at local_project.ABC_2_0.ABC.tSendMail_1Process(ABC.java:1186)
at local_project.ABC_2_0.ABC.tDBInput_2Process(ABC.java:924)
at local_project.ABC_2_0.ABC.runJobInTOS(ABC.java:1467)
at local_project.ABC_2_0.ABC.main(ABC.java:1318)
[statistics] disconnected

Job ABC ended at 14:46 11/08/2018. [exit code=1]
```

Could someone help me here?

Comment: It's hard to understand why exception occurs. Could you please attach your tSendMail_1 component configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the port no 3477 is open for sending mail.And try the same again